# Installing driver in raspberry pi

Tags: raspbian, driver

i dont know how to do it. I try to install driver into raspbian. I was download it manually and extract it into a folder. But I don't know how to run the setup.exe. Anyone please help me.

I try to install D-Link DWL-120+ driver.

Comment: Hey timekeeper, this has been put on hold by the community because it doesn't look as if you've done much of your own research, and the question is a very generic one. I'm glad you got an answer, but this type of question is not for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are ways to [Make Windows XP drivers work under Linux through ndiswrapper](http://blog.kasunbg.org/2010/02/make-windows-xp-drivers-work-under.html), but since you're using ARM processor, your best bet would be to get another cheap USB WiFi adapter, could be easily found for $10-15 on ebay.

It's very unlikely you'll be able to find working drivers for your current adapter.